# Is including the user field in two related models a bad practice? (Django)

Tags: django, database, django-models, database-design

I’m fairly new to Django and programming in general.

I’m building a tool for a friend in the construction industry. Basically the client bids for a tender and if they win they sign a contract. A contract can have multiple projects and a project can have multiple jobs. But the user should also be able to create a job for smaller projects that are not under a contract. Every job must be under a project.

If the user has a contract I want the user journey to be as the following:
Create a contract -> create a project -> create a job.

I want to link the contract to the user and to the job as well but I’m not sure if it’s right to include the user field twice in two related models. I’d like to know if my solution is wrong, and if there’s a better solution.

Thanks!

```
class Contract(TimeStampedModel):
    
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, blank=False, unique=False)
    starting_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Project(TimeStampedModel):
    
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.RESTRICT,
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, blank=False, unique=False)
    contract = models.ForeignKey(
        Contract,
        on_delete=models.RESTRICT,
        related_name='contract',
    )


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Job(TimeStampedModel):
    
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, blank=False, unique=False)
    starting_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
    location = models.PointField(geography=True, default=Point(0.0, 0.0))
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project,
        on_delete=models.RESTRICT,
    )


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Note: By default, django pluralizes model names by adding an S letter to them. So you don't need to set explicitely `verbose_name_plural` systematically (`Job` becomes `Jobs`, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong in including the user field in two (or more) related models.

However, you should avoid unecessary fields/relationships. For exemple, a `Job`, wich has an `owner` field, is linked to a `Project`, wich is itself linked to a `Contract` (wich has an `owner` field too). If those two owners can be different, then nothing's wrong.

However if those two owners are always the same, that's not a good database design. You should traverse the relationships to retrieve the owner instead.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the user can also create a project that is not linked to a contract. So I'm guessing that my solution is correct. Thanks!

Comment: Then your Project model needs to be related with your user model somehow, otherwise you won't be able to tell who owns a given project.

Comment: I will have to move the user filed from `Job` to `Project`, since every job must be under a project as I mentioned. Thanks for the help!